# problem with Unit Testing : promises , apollo server

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, jestjs, apollo-server

I have a problem with unit testing promises, I'm using apollo server and MongoDB as database 
this is an example of tests.

```js
it('Should return "Yacine" as user', done => {
  User.getUserByUserName({ username: 'Yacine' }).then(function(result) {
    expect(result).to.equal(User.findOne({ username: 'Yacine' }));
  });
  done();
});
```

that returns

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

  36 | };
  37 |
> 38 | module.exports.getUserByUserName = (root, {username}) => {
     |                                            ^
  39 |      //  console.log(username)
  40 |      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  41 |              user`.
```

and this is the function that I want to test

```js
module.exports.getUserByUserName = (root, { username }) => {
  //  console.log(username)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    user.findOne({ username }).exec((err, res) => {
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(res);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Mock DB calls or at least a DB. You can use https://github.com/mccormicka/Mockgoose for the latter.

Comment: but the problem i think is not about mongoose but is how to get the value of 'username' from the apollo server

Comment: I don't use Apollo and I'm not sure where Apollo code is in the code you posted. As for Mongoose part, it seems quite straightforward. Mock it. Is `User.getUserByUserName` that `module.exports.getUserByUserName` function you posted?

Comment: yeah that function

Comment: The error is there because it expects 2 args and you gave 1. `root` could likely be `{}` because it's unused. And you need to mock Mongoose query. Also, Mongoose supports promises and `new Promise` is antipattern; could be just  `user.findOne({username: username})`.

Comment: also you can set default value for parameter, e.g.
`module.exports.getUserByUserName = (root, {username} = {}) => {`
but then you probably need more checks